# Div scrollbar issue with IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, browser-scrollbars

We have parent DIV and inside parent div we have following structure.

```
Div Main
   table1
   table2
   Child div
Div Main end
```

Now our child div have overflow:auto. So when scrollbar comes and we scroll it, it also scroll table1 and table2. This happen only with IE8. Works fine with previous version of IE. There is no overflow property on .

Comment: Can you provide the actual HTML? And have you checked that the HTML validates? The behaviour you're describing sounds like you might have a subtle error in your HTML that makes IE8 interpret it differently to other browsers.

Comment: my HTML is huge. i need email id to send it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i provide height of child div in pixels, it works.